# Hadoop 2.6 - Range Partitioner

Tags: java, hadoop

I am working on the implementation of an `Algorithm: LIBRA to mitigate the data skew`, and a partition logic, named range partition is used.

Now, I have research on this, and found that Hadoop does come with this Range Partition function, but that's for version 1.4.1, here's the link:

```
http://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/mapreduce/lib/partition/RangePartitioner.html
```

The Hadoop Version, which I am using to implement this algorithm is 2.6. Is the Range Partitioner available with this version of hadoop?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provide is for Apache Accumulo which is a Key/value datastore built atop hadoop - but it is not native to hadoop itself.

https://accumulo.apache.org/

The partitioners available for 2.6 are

- BinaryPartitioner
- HashPartitioner
- KeyFieldBasedPartitioner
- TotalOrderPartitioner

So no there is no RangePartitioner for 2.6